# Cropper js настройка

Tags: javascript, изображения, crop

Здравствуйте за акцент извините )))
Использую cropper js
вот пример
https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/bqgNoa
Хочу сделать фиксирование height и width для cropper box
но не получается у меня
может кто то сделал такое и может меня помоч
вот мой код

```
    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            preview: '.preview',
            width: "100%",
            
            maxContainerWidth: 500,
            maxContainerHeight:  500,
            dragMode: 'move',
            aspectRatio: 16/ 9,
            autoCropArea: 0,
            restore: false,
            guides: true,
            center: true,
            highlight: false,
            cropBoxMovable: false,
            cropBoxResizable: false,
            toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
            viewMode: 0,
            responsive: true,

          
        });
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            preview: '.preview',
            width: "100%",
            maxContainerWidth: 500,
            maxContainerHeight:  500,
            dragMode: 'move',
            aspectRatio: 16/ 9,
            autoCropArea: 0,
            restore: false,
            guides: true,
            center: true,
            highlight: false,
            cropBoxMovable: false,
            cropBoxResizable: false,
            toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
            viewMode: 0,
            responsive: true,
            data:{
               width: 240,
               height:  90,
            },
        });
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
    });
```

Можешь попробовать, но это не точно:)

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже попробола не получается не точно резултат дает мне